# foreach está bugado no xml

Tags: php, html, xml

Pessoal estou quebrando a cabeça pra fazer um loop pelo foreach 
O consultarpagamento ele pega o link xml com a data 12/08/2019 com o token
quando eu clico pra consultar ele executa o consultarpagamento.php

e assim ele me devolve os valores
80079598 : 27951
80079409 : 27951
80079399 : 27951
80079005 : 27951
80078970 : 27951

So que o CODE ele pega certo so o ID que ele deveria pegar so pega 1 e não pega o resto

Codigo completo do XML

> xml

```
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<result>
<success>true</success>
<data>
<charges>
<charge>
<code>80079409</code>
<dueDate>16/08/2019</dueDate>
<checkoutUrl>
https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/checkout/5E4426FF099E1A1C88E388EEB03571610B43523DFB8C8356
</checkoutUrl>
<link>
https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/charge/boleto.pdf?token=539231:m:bb5b865782ceec0633b43500fe3a2633d51b43303e1c7674a80e0e12383df30b
</link>
<payNumber>BOLETO PAGO</payNumber>
<billetDetails>
<bankAccount>0655/46480-8</bankAccount>
<ourNumber>176/80079409-2</ourNumber>
<barcodeNumber>34191798300000021001768007940920655464808000</barcodeNumber>
<portfolio>176</portfolio>
</billetDetails>
<payments>
<payment>
<id>27942</id>
<amount>21.00</amount>
<date>12/08/2019</date>
<fee>3.90</fee>
<type>BOLETO</type>
<status>CONFIRMED</status>
<creditCardId/>
</payment>
</payments>
</charge>
<charge>
<code>80079399</code>
<dueDate>16/08/2019</dueDate>
<checkoutUrl>
https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/checkout/4E6E654050A7F01250197376A4F2DDC5E16C6B297FDA03F2
</checkoutUrl>
<link>
https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/charge/boleto.pdf?token=539221:m:2dedab41ca47e7c16c80b1da059be0bb83f2ef860b68302729671a18f18da845
</link>
<payNumber>BOLETO PAGO</payNumber>
<billetDetails>
<bankAccount>0655/46480-8</bankAccount>
<ourNumber>176/80079399-5</ourNumber>
<barcodeNumber>34191798300000032001768007939950655464808000</barcodeNumber>
<portfolio>176</portfolio>
</billetDetails>
<payments>
<payment>
<id>27941</id>
<amount>32.00</amount>
<date>12/08/2019</date>
<fee>3.90</fee>
<type>BOLETO</type>
<status>CONFIRMED</status>
<creditCardId/>
</payment>
</payments>
</charge>
<charge>
<code>80079005</code>
<dueDate>15/08/2019</dueDate>
<checkoutUrl>
https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/checkout/E383FCFDBB5E4A06E435BEE8DAC6B00D2B10E80D4A014538
</checkoutUrl>
<link>
https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/charge/boleto.pdf?token=538884:m:d53c8ed0e470656c103c8133b6346234049cf2c253eed0e1b1c7ce1918645c27
</link>
<payNumber>BOLETO PAGO</payNumber>
<billetDetails>
<bankAccount>0655/46480-8</bankAccount>
<ourNumber>176/80079005-8</ourNumber>
<barcodeNumber>34194798200000032001768007900580655464808000</barcodeNumber>
<portfolio>176</portfolio>
</billetDetails>
<payments>
<payment>
<id>27943</id>
<amount>32.00</amount>
<date>12/08/2019</date>
<fee>3.90</fee>
<type>BOLETO</type>
<status>CONFIRMED</status>
<creditCardId/>
</payment>
</payments>
</charge>
<charge>
<code>80078970</code>
<dueDate>15/08/2019</dueDate>
<checkoutUrl>
https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/checkout/57D3C0650A743272077CD024E456D1B58735E97B51DB6D13
</checkoutUrl>
<link>
https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/charge/boleto.pdf?token=538849:m:6e2680e3a5620076f0f97524c4270b72bf423f873d549973e89c05965f9409e7
</link>
<payNumber>BOLETO PAGO</payNumber>
<billetDetails>
<bankAccount>0655/46480-8</bankAccount>
<ourNumber>176/80078970-4</ourNumber>
<barcodeNumber>34195798200000032001768007897040655464808000</barcodeNumber>
<portfolio>176</portfolio>
</billetDetails>
<payments>
<payment>
<id>27944</id>
<amount>32.00</amount>
<date>12/08/2019</date>
<fee>3.90</fee>
<type>BOLETO</type>
<status>CONFIRMED</status>
<creditCardId/>
</payment>
</payments>
</charge>
</charges>
</data>
</result>
```

> consultarPagamentov.php

```
<?php 
    include("../../conexao.php");


if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
    $query4 = "select * from funcionalidades where id = '1'";
    $result4 = mysqli_query($conexao, $query4);
    $dados4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4);

      if(mysqli_num_rows ($result4) > 0) {

      }
    if($dados4['status'] == 1) {
    if (isset($_POST['data'])){
            $data =  $_POST['data'];
            $token = "3C9D99D90FF1F6F9AF2353D708CA2C59BFC6828CBDFF4ED2254F9CE4D3EBA416";

            function gerar($token,$data){
                $url = "https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/integration/api/v1/list-charges?";
                $url .= "token=".$token."&";
                $url .= "beginPaymentDate=".$data."&";
                $url .= "responseType=XML";

                return $url;
            }

              $xml = gerar($token,$data);
              $boleto = simplexml_load_file($xml);
            $capeta = $boleto->data->charges->charge;
            foreach($capeta as $dados){

             echo $dados->code;
         echo "<br>";
             echo $dados->payNumber;
              echo "<br>";
            }


    }
    }else{
        echo "Função desabilitada contate um administrador para fazer a liberação!";
    }
?>
```

Ele pega as informações correta já no exemplo de baixo ele não pega todos ID do payments->payment do xml

> consultarPagamentov.php

```
 <?php 
    include("../../conexao.php");


if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
    $query4 = "select * from funcionalidades where id = '1'";
    $result4 = mysqli_query($conexao, $query4);
    $dados4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4);

      if(mysqli_num_rows ($result4) > 0) {

      }
    if($dados4['status'] == 1) {
    if (isset($_POST['data'])){
            $data =  $_POST['data'];
            $token = "3C9D99D90FF1F6F9AF2353D708CA2C59BFC6828CBDFF4ED2254F9CE4D3EBA416";

            function gerar($token,$data){
                $url = "https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/integration/api/v1/list-charges?";
                $url .= "token=".$token."&";
                $url .= "beginPaymentDate=".$data."&";
                $url .= "responseType=XML";

                return $url;
            }

              $xml = gerar($token,$data);
              $boleto = simplexml_load_file($xml);
            $capeta = $boleto->data->charges->charge->payments->payment;
            foreach($capeta as $dados){

             echo $dados->id;
         echo "";
             echo $dados->amount;

            }


    }
    }else{
        echo "Função desabilitada contate um administrador para fazer a liberação!";
    }
?>
```

> consultar.php

```
<form action="consultarPagamentov" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Data</label>
            <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="data" id="data" placeholder="Data">

          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Consultar</button>

            </form>
```

Comment: $capeta foi ótimo kkkkk

Comment: so de raiva coloquei kk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edward, altere essas linhas do seu arquivo:

```
$capeta = $boleto->data->charges->charge->payments->payment;
            foreach($capeta as $dados){

             echo $dados->id;
         echo "";
             echo $dados->amount;

            }
```

Por essas:

```
$capeta = $boleto->data->charges->charge;
    foreach($capeta as $dados){
         echo "ID: " . $dados->payments->payment->id . '<br>';
         echo "ID: " . $dados->payments->payment->amount . '<br><br>';

    }
```

Comment: Leandro esqueci de colocar o sandbox link la encima elas já estão fechadas..

Comment: Corrigi já o post verifica lá agora

Comment: Esse link ele é implantando dentro da busca ai forma o link quando eu clico em consultar

Comment: tudo bem, com as informações que você postou para funcionar é somente fechando as tags e irá funcionar. Deverá corrigir sua pergunta inteira, pois o link que vc colocou do sandbox está diferente do xml que vc colocou como exemplo e assim, não conseguimos te ajudar, outra coisa. Vc não postou qual é a sua função gerar(). Sem essas informações também não conseguimos te ajudar. Infelizmente.

Comment: Leandro arrumei o codigo inteiro lá
e coloquei o que preciso

Comment: post sua função gerar, pois se o problema não está no xml estará nela.

Comment: Pronto Leandro, lembrando que ela funciona o que não funciona é o exemplo 2 de exibir o codigo do payments

Comment: a sua repetição está no charge e não no payments. Depois disto vc consegue o que precisa, alterei minha resposta

Comment: Bah valeu de mais funcionou aqui